# jQuery & replaceWith(): reloading page every other time

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code reloads the entire page rather than simply replacing the `#form` element every other time. Can someone suggest a fix so that only `#form` is replaced and the entire page not reloaded?

jQuery:

```
  $("#login").submit(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(html) {
        var htmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(html);
        $("#form").replaceWith(htmlString);
        $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: $("#message").offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
    return false;
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="form">
  <form id="login" action="submit.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

It doesn't seem to me that replaceWith() would eliminate the bindings, but perhaps it does . . .

Comment: Can you post the HTML that you're working with? It would help tremendously.

Comment: Check the console to see if there are any errors.  If you have an error prior to `return false;` false will not be returned and the form will submit.

Comment: No errors are shown in the console.

Comment: Is your js code in a $(document).ready() enclosure? Is it possible that sometimes the jquery event is not bound to #login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It doesn't seem to me that replaceWith() would overwrite the bindings, but perhaps it does . . .

Inherently.

You bound an event to a DOM node, then replaced that DOM node with something else (which had no bindings).

Try [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for *auto-rebinding* <sup>(can't think of a better term)</sup> the event handlers to the DOM node matching a given selector, *at any point in time that such a match comes into existence*.

Answer (score 0):

your form has an id attribute *forms* `<div id="forms">`

but your jquery selector targets *form* `$("#form").replaceWith(htmlString);`

Comment: That was a typo in the question.  My apologies.  I fixed the typo in the question. The problem still exists.